# called object is not a function - how to properly nest headers to call methods

Tags: c

I have a layered ADT which I am trying to call a lower member from the client. Specifically, I have a Graph ADT that relies on a List ADT to store the adjacencies. I am having issues with calling methods such as length from the List ADT within the client.

I have List.h included in Graph.h, and then Graph.h included in the client. (but adding an include List.h to the client does not change anything). The compiler has no problem with calling the List constructor in Graph.h, but when I call List methods such as length it tells me that "called object length is not a function".

GraphClient.c exerpt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Graph.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
List L = newList();
printf("%d",length(L));
}
```

List.c exerpts

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "List.h"

List newList(void) {
    List L = malloc(sizeof (ListObj));
    L->front = L->back = L->current = NULL;
    L->cursor = -1;
    L->length = 0;
    return (L);
}
int length(List L) {
    if (L == NULL) {
        printf("List error: calling length on NULL List reference");
        exit(1);
    }
    return (L->length);
}
```

Graph.c exerpts

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Graph.h"
#include "List.h"
```

Am I tiering the includes correctly? The program works fine if I don't try to call List methods inside the client, but without that I will not meet specifications.

Comment: Did you not `#include "List.h"` in your `int main(...){...}`?

Comment: Should we guess at the contents of `List.h`? And the reasons you don't post a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org)?

Answer (score 1):

In the provided code, you show that you needed to `#include "List.h"` in your `Graph.c` file. This is presumably to allow `Graph.c` code to call the functions implemented in `List.c`. `GraphClient.c` is no different in that regard. Add `#include "List.h"` there as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Graph.h"
#include "List.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    List L = newList();
    printf("%d",length(L));
}
```